# The function cy.clock(), cy.tick() aren't working

Tags: typescript, automation, automated-tests, cypress, e2e

Use this functions to write e2e tests with cypress. Need to check that after few minutes I can send request and receive successful message.

```
it.only('successful message', () => {
    $.name.type('name')
    $.phone.type('444444444')
    $.user.type('test@test.com')
    $.password.type('password')

    $.button.click()
    cy.get('div').contains('Resend message').click()
    $$.toastRed
      .contains(
        'Please wait before requesting a new confirmation'
      )
      .should('be.visible')

    cy.clock()
    cy.tick(300000)

    cy.get('div').contains('Resend message').click()
    $$.toastGr
      .contains('Resent')
      .should('be.visible')
      .should('have.attr', 'color', styling.green)
```

But after running this test see that time is gone but anyway an app behave yourself like there is no cy.tick() function. If I replace cy.clock() higher, I just see empty screen or the test stopped before cy.clock(). How to solve this problem and is it possible to emulate such things?

Comment: Why are you using jquery and cypress commands like this? Not likely, but could be part of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm here looking for a different bug but as far as I'm aware you definitely need to call `cy.clock()` before anything else. If you have beforeEach defined that might be your problem.